# Notepad++ - Find and replace both opening and closing tags while keeping the content intact?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Let's say I wanted to replace something like this:

```
\section{Introduction}
```

with this:

```
<h1>Introduction</h1>
```

in notepad++.

Essentially, find and replace all the opening tags (in this case the "\section{" part) and closing tags (the "}") with different opening and closing tags,[image: Something like this]

Something like this. Except, of course, the text in between the tags stays the same. Is this possible within notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find what: `\\section\{(.+)\}`

Replace with: `<h1>\1</h1>`

Here, the parentheses `(.+)` define a group that consists of one or more character, and `\1` references the contents of the group.

Answer (score 0):

**Search :**

```
\\section\{(.*)\}
```

**And replace with :**

```
<h1>\1</h1>
```

`\1` will be replaced with your first regexp result.

**I.e. searching :**

```
\{(.*), (.*)\}
```

And replacing with :

```
[\1, \2]
```

Will transform `{foo, bar}` into `[foo, bar]` :

`\1` = foo
`\2` = bar

Comment: Oh yes nevermind, i'll edit. Why are all text editors using different syntax :')